# Python Regenerate Random Numbers if Condition is not met

Tags: python, class, oop, random, initialization

I want to evaluate an expression and regenerate the random numbers in `__init__` method of Class if the condition is met. Code for that is below

```
import random

class RandomNumbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.BASE_A = random.randint(2, 10)
        self.BASE_B = random.randint(2, 10)

        self.EXPONENT_N = random.randint(2, 7)
        self.EXPONENT_P = random.randint(2, 7)

        # Ensure result 
        while self.BASE_A ** self.EXPONENT_N - \
                self.BASE_B ** self.EXPONENT_P == 0:
            # re initiate BASE_A, BASE_B, EXPONENT_N, EXPONENT_P
            pass

    def generate(self):
        return self.BASE_A, self.EXPONENT_N, self.BASE_B, \
               self.EXPONENT_P
```

How can I call `__init__` within `__init__` if `self.BASE_A ** self.EXPONENT_N - self.BASE_B ** self.EXPONENT_P == 0` ?

Comment: you can't   you would want to create a seperate method and call that

Comment: So I can do that in `generate` method?

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate method just to assign values like @Alexander's answer does.

Instead, put the assignments in a `while` loop, and `break` the loop only if the desired condition is met:

```
class RandomNumbers:
    def __init__(self):
        while True:
            self.BASE_A = random.randint(2, 10)
            self.BASE_B = random.randint(2, 10)
            self.EXPONENT_N = random.randint(2, 7)
            self.EXPONENT_P = random.randint(2, 7)
            if self.BASE_A ** self.EXPONENT_N - self.BASE_B ** self.EXPONENT_P != 0:
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this.  assign all of the values in a seperate method and if they are incorrect call that same method again.

```
import random

class RandomNumbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.assign_values()
        while (self.BASE_A ** self.EXPONENT_N - 
               self.BASE_B ** self.EXPONENT_P == 0):
            self.assign_valuse()

    def assign_values(self):
        self.BASE_A = random.randint(2, 10)
        self.BASE_B = random.randint(2, 10)
        self.EXPONENT_N = random.randint(2, 7)
        self.EXPONENT_P = random.randint(2, 7)


    def generate(self):
        return self.BASE_A, self.EXPONENT_N, self.BASE_B, \
               self.EXPONENT_P
```